# Odd different when using .populate() on a separate method between with findById() and with find()

Tags: typescript, mongoose

So I read my senior's code and I see he did something like this:

```
const getTechnicianByIdQuery = await TechnicianModel.findById({id: someId});
const wantedTechnician = await this.populateSingleTechnician(getTechnicianByIdQuery);

const populateSingleTechnician(technician: any): Promise<Technician>{
    const populatedTechnician = await technician
        .populate({path: 'salon',})
        .populate({path: 'user',})
        .execPopulate();
    return populatedTechnician;
};
```

This code works fine, and I think his way of doing this is cool that allow us to reuse code so I try to do the same with a different search using find() instead of findById():

```
const getTechnicianBySalonQuery = await TechnicianModel.find({salon: someSalonId})
const wantedTechnicianGroup = await this.populateTechnicianGroup(getTechnicianBySalonQuery);

const populateSingleTechnician(technicianGroup: any): Promise<Technician[]>{
    const populatedTechnicians = await technicianGroup
        .populate({path: 'salon',})
        .populate({path: 'user',})
        .execPopulate();
    return populatedTechnicians;
};
```

My code gives error:

> > { errors:
> >            [ GraphQLError {
> >                message: 'technicianGroup.populate is not a function',
> >                locations: [Array],
> >                path: [Array] } ],
> >           data: null }

How come my code gives this error while his code works fine and returns the populated data? If we say separating the populating process, which is usually put in as a chaining operator, caused this error, I still wonder what difference that make the first code block works but not mine.

On the other note, I have done the tradition way of chaining populated() to the query and it worked  fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When chaining, you should not use of `await` keyword. When you use `await` you execute the query.

Look at the [documentation example](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find).

```
const getTechnicianByIdQuery = TechnicianModel.findById({
  id: someId,
});

const wantedTechnician = await this.populateSingleTechnician(getTechnicianByIdQuery);

const populateSingleTechnician(technician: any): Promise<Technician> {
  const populatedTechnician = await technician
    .populate({
      path: 'salon',
    })
    .populate({
      path: 'user',
    })
    .execPopulate();
  return populatedTechnician;
};
```

---

The first one is working because `await findById` returns you a `mongoose.Document` that have the `.populate` [method available](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-populate). When in the second case, the `mongoose.Document[]` doesn't have the `populate` method (because it's an array).

---

I see that you use of typescript, I highly recommend you to type your variables. You would have seen an error at `technician.populate` if `technician: any` was replaced by the correct type.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, @Gregory! Another of my concerns is that  without `await`, will `getTechnicianByIdQuery` always fetch all of the collections that it should get on time? Will the second `await` do the work of waiting?

Comment: The call to `find()` will returns you a `Query` object. At this point no interaction with the database has been made. When you finally call `exec()` (use exec instead of execPopulate) then mongoose will execute the entire query pipeline you described and fetch all the data. To resume : Yes the second await will give you all the answers